# How do I avoid restarting Android Studio because of a Kotlin build error: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, interface

I have a Android App written in Java and am now trying out Kotlin for the first time. I've created a new activity using Kotlin that should be called from Java Code via 'startActivityforResult'. The IDE (probably the Kotlin Plugin?) automatically added everything that was necessary to the gradle build files. The new activity uses a keys from the main activity to identify and enumerate parameters and return values. No when I try to build this app in Android Studio 3.3.1 using the Android Gradle plugin v3.3.1 and Kotlin 1.3.20.

Usually this results in an Error: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath ...

The classes listed there are 2 of my own classes (so not a problem with dependencies), the supertype in both cases is the same, namely a Java interface

```
interface AllDataLoadedListener {
    void allDataLoaded();
}
```

located together with other interface definitions in a file named DatabaseInterfaces.java.

Invalidating the cache and restarting Android Studio as proposed [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-custom-view-class-implements-an-interface-that-cannot-be-resolved-in-app-compiledebugkotlinafterjava-identical-java-version-works-fine/1594/3) helps (not always but mostly), but this step is apparently necessary after EVERY code change which gets annoying very fast.

What is the root problem and how can this be avoided and/or fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, while it is frowned upon to declare multiple interfaces in one file the java compiler still allows it, the Kotlin compiler currently does not.
Splitting up the Interface file into files each with a single (1 line) interface with their respective type names also as file names does the trick.

Comment: Well, the Java spec is that you can only have one public member per file.If it's the visibility that messes with it, that's the explanation.